# Hardness of an instance of a problem independent of algorithms?

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, graphs, algorithm-analysis

The paper “Where the *really* hard problems are” (https://www.ijcai.org/Proceedings/91-1/Papers/052.pdf) and others that cite it provide evidence that lots of algorithms for many NP complete problems (when suitably parametrised) perform poorly on the problems that lie on the phase transition from under constrained to over constrained which occurs as the parameter is increased. Is there a way to assign hardness to an instance of say 3SAT, without invoking or involving a specific algorithm that may perform poorly on that instance? Or is this line of thinking necessarily restricted to specific algorithms?

Comment: If you show that problem X is NP-hard even when restricted to instances of type Y, then you have certified that instances of type Y are hard.

Comment: I don't think it makes sense to talk about the hardness of a specific instance except w.r.t. a specific algorithm, since for each instance there is some algorithm that begins with "If (input = thatInstance) return correctAnswer".

Comment: @YuvalFilmus so is there some notion of minimality or some (partial) order based on containment etc among the types of instances of say 3SAT, basically so that we may put our finger on only the hard instances?

Comment: All hard instances are as hard.

Comment: @j_random_hacker You can define a meaningful notion of hardness of an instance for some problems in some models of computation. See for exemple "Instance Optimal Geometric Algorithms" by Ahshani et al., and the references therein.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus what do you mean by hard instances?

Comment: I mean the instances of type Y I mentioned above.

Comment: You cannot assign hardness to a specific instance. Every specific instance is solved by a constant time algorithm. You have to talk about families of instances, say one for infinitely many values of $n$. Even in that case, it's not so clear how you would argue that they are hard.

Comment: In practice, we only talk about (families of) instances which are hard for specific algorithmic paradigms, such as LP hierarchies or SDP hierarchies.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus okay, thank you!